# how to remove a suffix of a string after a character in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a string like this.

> 30: sometext 57: sometext ....

I want to iterate over the numbers that come before the colon inside a shell script.

Comment: What is your expected output for the above string and what did you try?

Comment: give this a try: `grep -oP '\d+(?=:)' <<< $yourString`

Answer (score 1):

> With egrep - Vertical Output

```
echo "30: sometext 57: sometext" | egrep -o '[0-9][0-9]'
30
57
```

> With awk -  Horizontal Output

```
echo "30: sometext 57: sometext"|awk -F'["|:| ]' '{print $1, $(NF-2)}'
30 57
```